# hard disk suddnely disappear

Tags: hard-drive

My hard disk has suddenly disappeared and doesn't show up again.

- I can't find it in disk management or device manager.
- I can find it in intel optane memory and I can see the temperature of the drive.
- I can see it in the bios in resting a non raid disk (I didn't click because I think will lose all my data)

How can I get my files back?

[image: intel optane memory]

[image: disk management]

[image: device manager]

Comment: Haven't you see the SMART device status "at risk" in your first screenshot? That means the drive has detected a serious failure - in other words the HDD may be defect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk has failed and has become unusable.

To recover your data will require a data recovery service that has
the equipment to read the magnetic bits from the disk.

If your disk is under warranty, then get in touch
with their Support team, and they may recover your data for free.

Otherwise, you will need to contact a data recovery company
near you and send them the disk for saving your data.
Unfortunately, such services are costly.

Comment: As others stated, the disk is likely damaged. You can try putting it in another PC, or in an external USB HDD case, and it *might* be possible to recover some data... or not. There are commercial data recovery services, but that would be some expense. Best bet is to recover your data from the last full disk image you made.

Comment: thanks mate i think i will get new one idk if there is a company can do it near me but i will search for one